# customize button of auto fileupload in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using the fileUploadController of primefaces

```
<h:form>  

   <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"  
        update="messages" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  

   <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

</h:form>
```

And I would like to know if it is possible to customize  the upload button(for example changing its name from "Choose" to "Checkin")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use label attribute...

```
<p:fileUpload label="Checkin" mode="advanced" />
```

Also other buttons labels are

> *uploadLabel*: Label of the upload button.
>
> *cancelLabel*: Label of the cancel button.

Hope this helps.